# $\int\frac{\sqrt{9x^2-25}}{x}dx$. Using Trigonometric substitution, how to solve an integral when leading coefficient under radical isn't Unity?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, trigonometric-integrals

**Problem**
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{9x^2-25}}{x}dx$$

**My Approach**
I identify this (perhaps incorrectly) as a secant problem, where: $$3x=5\sec\theta$$ and $$dx=\frac{5}{3}\sec\theta\tan\theta\; d\theta$$

Then, substituting back, we get:

$$\int\frac{5\tan\theta\;\frac{5}{3}\sec\theta\tan\theta}{\frac{5}{3}\sec\theta}\;d\theta$$

Reducing I get (Maybe incorrectly)

$$\int5\tan^2\theta\;d\theta$$

And finally, using $\tan^2\theta = \sec^2\theta-1$, I get:

$$5\int(\sec^2\theta-1)\;d\theta= 5\tan\theta-5\theta + C$$

Now, substituting back in for $\theta$, where $\tan\theta = \frac{\sqrt{9x^2\;-\;25}}{5}$ , I get

$$ \boxed{\sqrt{9x^2-25} - 5arcsec(x) + C}$$

However, this is not the answer my professor has listed in the answer key. He gives the solution as

$$\boxed{-\frac{3\sqrt{9x^2-25}}{x^2}+\frac{27}{50}arcsec(x) + C}$$

Now, his answers have been wrong before but I think I just made a major error along the way. The $arcsec$ at the end tells me I was kind of on the right track, but the fraction in front of it tells me I messed up big somewhere. Did I make a mistake converting the radical for trigonometric substitution, make a reducing error, or both? Should I have tackled this problem using a different technique?

Comment: Your version looks more correct, except that it is not $5\text{arcsec}(x)$. Closer is $5\text{arcsec}(3x/5)$ except there may be an issue when $x$ is negative.

Comment: That is true, good point. There is one mistake for sure. I just can't see how my professor's answer is correct, it doesn't even seem like i'm close...

Comment: After making the adjustment mentioned in that first comment, have you tried checking your solution (take a derivative) and your professors?

Comment: @FuegoJohnson But everyone makes mistakes.  Messy substitutions and all that, when learning calculus the first time, we all make mistakes.  Take it from a pro (e.g. not me) ;D

Comment: The good thing is that one can easily check answers by differentiating, which is usually easier. And a note: If one let $u=\sqrt{9x^2-25}$ then the natural form of the answer becomes $$\sqrt{9x^2-25}-5\arctan\bigl(\frac15\sqrt{9x^2-25}\bigr)+C.$$ This just shows that answers might look different. I don't think that is the case for the teacher here, though...

Comment: Thanks for the encouragement, guys(or gals). I have been working my butt off to learn calculus, I really do enjoy it, but these integration techniques can be tough! Seeing his answer really threw me for a loop, I thought I messed something up bad....